# How to exit out of While loop is condition meet

Tags: python

I have a infinite loop need to exit the script if condition meets and print my expected output

**Code:**

```
import random

stud=[0,0]
studnme = ['a','b']

while (stud[0] !=50 or stud[1] !=50):
    if flag = 0:
        lucky_draw = random.randint(1,6)
        stud_marks = stud[0] + lucky_draw
        stud[0]    = stud[0] + lucky_draw  
        flag=1 
    else:
        lucky_draw = random.randint(1,6)
        stud_marks = stud[1] + lucky_draw
        stud[0]    = stud[1] + lucky_draw  
        flag=0
```

**Output :**

```
Student 'a' You have reached : 50
Student 'b' You have reached : 34
```

Need to print who as highest points

Comment: `if flag = 0:` should be `if flag == 0:`

Answer (score 4):

The values you're testing to exit the loop are incremented by random values, so they're not guaranteed to hit 50 exactly. Make the loop run while those values are less than 50.

```
while (stud[0] < 50 and stud[1] < 50):
```

Comment: is there any way  can exact 100 reached then only exit

Comment: @nodehep223 Yes, you could loop while the sum of the two values is not equal to 100,  but you'd have the same problem. Since you increment by randint(1,6), you might skip over 100 without hitting it exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

stud=[0,0]
studnme = ['a','b']
flag=0
while (stud[0] <=50 or stud[1] <=50):
    if flag == 0:
        lucky_draw = random.randint(1,6)
        stud_marks = stud[0] + lucky_draw
        stud[0]    = stud[0] + lucky_draw  
        flag=1 
    else:
        lucky_draw = random.randint(1,6)
        stud_marks = stud[1] + lucky_draw
        stud[1]    = stud[1] + lucky_draw  
        flag=0      
print(f'Student a you have reached :{stud[0]}')
print(f'Student b you have reached :{stud[1]}')
```

First of all you have not defined the flag, so set it to 0 or 1 and also the condition that you have kept should be a little changed  , that is as any of the student has marks greater than 50 the program should terminate. Please check the above code.